Tkinter Error when using '.grid' (Code is unfinished)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kalybarly/.py", line 22, in <module>
    arial.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2522, in grid_configure
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack

...
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

fnt = 'Arial'

root.title('Text Editor')
root.geometry('800x500')

ttl = tk.Label(root, text='Text Editor', font=('Arial', 25), height=3) 
ttl.pack(padx=10, pady=20)

text = tk.Text(root, font=(fnt, 16))
text.pack(padx=0, pady = 10)

button_frame = tk.Frame(root)
button_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
button_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
button_frame.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

arial = tk.Button(root, text='Arial', font=('Arial',10), height=1)
arial.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

button_frame.pack(fill='x')

root.mainloop()


The error message means exactly what it says.  You've got three widgets using .pack(), and one using .grid(), all children of the root window.  Perhaps your Button was intended to be a child of button_frame, instead?

The error you're encountering is due to the fact that you're trying to use both pack and grid geometry managers in the same parent widget (root). In Tkinter, you can only use one geometry manager per parent widget.
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

fnt = 'Arial'

root.title('Text Editor')
root.geometry('800x500')

ttl = tk.Label(root, text='Text Editor', font=('Arial', 25), height=3) 
ttl.pack(padx=10, pady=20)

text = tk.Text(root, font=(fnt, 16))
text.pack(padx=0, pady = 10)

button_frame = tk.Frame(root)
button_frame.pack(fill='x')

arial = tk.Button(button_frame, text='Arial', font=('Arial',10), height=1)
arial.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

root.mainloop()

